# Do the properties of metric completeness and algebraic closure characterize the complex numbers up to isomorphism?

Tags: complex-numbers

If not, are there any such properties?

Comment: what kind of isomorphism are you looking for?

Comment: I guess I mean isomorphism as a topological field.

Comment: What got me thinking about this is the definition of the reals as the unique complete ordered field. Im wondering if there's an analogous definition for C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find the topic where I thought I saw this a couple days ago, so here it is:

Short answer:  No. There are infinitely many fields which are complete and algebraically closed and not isomorphic to $\Bbb C$.

You want a minimal algebraically closed, complete, archimedean field containing $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ or $\Bbb R$, or something of the like. You could also use *locally compact*, archimedean, algebraically closed and drop the minimal assumption.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger The algebraic closure of the $p$-adic numbers.